# How do I find an annotation handle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, object, handle

I'm trying to implement a modified version of [datetick2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20422-datetick-with-zooming-panning-and-subplots) from the MATLAB FEX. When plots are zoomed in on a small date range, the day/month/year, etc. isn't shown, depending on the range of times in the plot. I'd like to put a 'dd-mmm-yyyy' formatted starting date as an annotation in the bottom left corner of the figure. No problem, that's done.

However, next I want to have it update if the user selects a different date range with the zoom function. Instead of passing more handles, I want to just find the annotation. However, [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html) doesn't seem to work for the hggroup type, which is what annotations fall under. Am I using it wrong?

Here's a code example:

```
>> times=now-[50:-5:0];
>> days=times-times(1);
>> plot(times,days)
>> datetick2()
>> xlabel('Date')
>> ylabel('Days')
>> title('Example')
>> initialdate=datestr(min(get(gca,'xlim')),'dd-mmm-yyyy');
>> txt=annotation('textbox', [.01,.01,.1,.05],...
                  'string',  initialdate,...
                  'Linestyle','none');
>> 
>> 
>> findobj('type','hggroup')

ans =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1

>> get(txt,'type')

ans =

hggroup

>> findobj('type','axes')

ans =

  270.0034
```

As you can see, findobj doesn't work, but if I use the handle I defined in the workspace, the type pops right out as `hggroup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to first set the root [`'ShowHiddenHandles'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/rootobject_props.html#ShowHiddenHandles) to `'on'`, then try using [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html) to find your object, then set it back to the default `'off'`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I added a tag property to the annotation as well, just to make things even easier.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `findobj`, I use [FINDALL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/findall.html), since it allows me to keep hidden handles hidden. `findall` needs a handle starting from which it recursively searches the children. `findall(0,'Tag','myTag') finds all objects tagged`myTag`(0 is the handle to root),`findall(gcf,'Tag','myTag') finds the objects tagged `myTag` that are associated with the current figure (including the figure itself, in case it has the right tag).